# What precedes "sharing the emotion labor" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The sentence is:

> Imagine a community printer, sharing the emotional labor and expense
> of keeping track of ink cartridges and paper.

In this sentence, what precedes *sharing the emotional labor*? Is it *Imagine* as in *Imagine a community printer and imagine sharing the emotional labor*? Or is it *Imagine a community printer that shares the emotional labor* (this sounds weird to me since it's a printer after all)?

Comment: Looks like a dangling participle; clearly the emotions are generated by the community who share the labor and expense. Anybody who's lived with several roommates will understand the reference, though the grammar is incomplete.

Comment: "emotional labour" looks to me like a bad translation of ***hassle***

Comment: "Emotional labor" is an established term that comes from sociology, and was originally useful in explaining jobs that require a lot of emotional regulation (PR, flight attendants, other service work). The word was adapted more generally to mean something like *cognitive load* - the extra labor of keeping track of pertinent everyday details. That *is* a hassle, but even in this extended use, *emotional labor* is more specific than *hassle*; enduring a long commute is a hassle, but isn't really emotional labor.